# Объединить в строки списки строк

Tags: python

Как объединить в строку только списки строк, но не строки?
Есть список, в котором есть как списки строк, так и просто строки. Надо списки строк объединить, а просто строки не трогать.
Думал использовать метод `join`, но он объединяет все без разбора. Например,

```
a = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', ['sit', 'amet']]
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(', '.join(i))
print(a)
print(b)
```

выводит

```
['Lorem', 'ipsum', ['sit', 'amet']]
['L, o, r, e, m', 'i, p, s, u, m', 'sit, amet']
```

А надо, чтобы программа вывела

```
['Lorem', 'ipsum', ['sit', 'amet']]
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'sit, amet']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', ['sit', 'amet']]
b = []
for i in a:
    if type(i) == list:
        b.append(", ".join(b for b in i))
    else:
        b.append(i)
print(a) # ['Lorem', 'ipsum', ['sit', 'amet']]
print(b) # ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'sit, amet']
```

или

```
a = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', ['sit', 'amet']]
b = [', '.join(i) if type(i) == list else i for i in a]
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: Первый вариант понятнее. Второй короче и, наверное, оптимальнее, но я так не умею.

Comment: А почему нельзя просто b.append(", ".join(i)) ? Результат ведь тот же.

Comment: @havon второй вариант это генератор первого варианта.

Answer (score 3):

```
b = [', '.join(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in a]
```